# How do I perform an action when a jquery ui tabs is shown

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

How do I perform an action when a tab is shown?

I've tried the example from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show but don't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
$( "#General_Files" ).bind( "tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
  console.log('Performing action here');
});
```

Where General_Files is the ID of the tab.

I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.21 and jquery-1.7.2.

Thanks h0tw1r3

Solution:
Here's how I got it to work.

```
<div id="tabwidget">
    <ul><li><a href="#General_Files">General Files</a></li></ul>
    <div id="General_Files">content</div>
</div>
```

The following worked.

```
$( "#tabwidget" ).bind( "tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
  console.log('Performing action here');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> General_files is the ID of the tab.

Change to the ID of the tab widget and use `ui.panel` to access the actual tab in the function.